# Dumping bad requests

Tags: rest, jersey, dropwizard, bean-validation

I have a service implemented with Dropwizard and I need to dump incorrect requests somewhere.

I saw that there is a [possibility](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/manual/validation.html) to customise the error message by registering `ExceptionMapper<JerseyViolationException>`. But I need to have the complete request (headers, body) and not only `ConstraintViolations`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject [`ContainerRequest`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26-b09/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest.html) into the `ExceptionMapper`. You need to inject it as a `javax.inject.Provider` though, so that you can lazily retrieve it. Otherwise you will run into scoping problems.

```java
@Provider
public class Mapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {
    
    @Inject
    private javax.inject.Provider<ContainerRequest> requestProvider;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        ContainerRequest request = requestProvider.get();
    }
}
```

(This also works with constructor argument injection instead of field injection.)

In the `ContainerRequest`, you can get headers with `getHeaderString()` or `getHeaders()`. If you want to get the body, you need to do a little hack because the entity stream is already read by Jersey by the time the mapper is reached. So we need to implement a `ContainerRequestFilter` to buffer the entity.

```java
public class EntityBufferingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        ContainerRequest request = (ContainerRequest) containerRequestContext;
        request.bufferEntity();
    }
}
```

You might not want this filter to be called for *all* requests (for performance reasons), so you might want to use a [`DynamicFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9748) to register the filter just on methods that use bean validation (or use [Name Binding](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9675)).

Once you have this filter registered, you can read the body using `ContainerRequest#readEntity(Class)`. You use this method just like you would on the client side with `Response#readEntity()`. So for the class, if you want to keep it generic, you can use `String.class` or `InputStream.class` and convert the `InputStream` to a String.

```java
ContainerRequest request = requestProvider.get();
String body = request.readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot !!