# Get request body in failed access of method with POST annotation

Tags: java, post, jersey, jax-rs, notsupportedexception

I have a RESTful web service with an `@POST` annotated method that throws an exception when the request content type cannot be consumed. I would like to see what exactly went wrong. For this I would like to access all the details of the failed POST call, such as the body content. For this I created an `@Provider` catching `NotSupportedException`. I still have problems finding a way to get the desired details though. How would I do that?

The @POST annotated method:

```
@Path("/language")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class LanguageResource {
    @POST
    public Response postLanguages(Session session) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                       .entity(Mock.getLanguages())
                       .build();
    }
}
```

The @Provider:

```
@Provider
public class NotSupportedMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotSupportedException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotSupportedException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.toString());

        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
                       .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Jersey?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Yes

Comment: You can check out my answer [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52894253/2587435)