# Providing localized error responses with Jersey

Tags: java, error-handling, localization, internationalization, jersey

I am using `Jersey 2.25` (via `Dropwizard`) in a `Java microservice` and need to provide localized error responses. The language to use will be passed in with each `HTTP` request.
Currently, I have several `ExceptionMappers` in place which create error responses from Exceptions.

I don't want to pass around the language to every place where one of my exceptions is created and thrown. I also would like to avoid storing the language into thread local storage, at least when using it to create exceptions because that (amongst other reasons) would make async execution more cumbersome.
It might be the last resort to get at the language inside the `ExceptionMapper` though, but this is less easy to maintain than real API usage.

So, is there an API to get at the request data inside the `ExceptionMapper`, or some similar mechanism to provide error responses with access to request data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52894253/2587435

Comment: Very nice! Using injection works! I did not know that that is possible.